# How to change the color of first row of first table using css

Tags: css

I have a table structure like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Surmane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>AA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>AAA</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>AAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>BB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>BBB</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>CC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>CCC</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to change the color of first table->first row (Name, Info, Surname) using css.
The css should not affect the second table->first row(Id,10)

Please suggest me any idea
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:not(td) > table > tbody > tr:first-child td {
   color: red
}
```

Since there's no information about the parent, siblings and outer markup I've specified `:not(td)` as admittable direct parent of your outermost table (that is *any element except a td*)

Furthermore, since you have also inner tables I had to specify `> tbody >` because browsers usually insert a automatically a `tbody` element  and without it the selector would also match the first row of inner table (where `id 10` is specified).

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEPLEb

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Hi all,
According to my requirement i cannot modify this html code. so neither i add class nor add id in table.
The suggestion of Fabrizio Calderan is correct. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: Knew there was a better way of doing this than my answer. This is really good to know

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer using inline css:

```
<tr style="color:red;">
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a class to the first `<tr>` like `<tr class="color">` and then just change the color with `.color { color: #fff; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change colour with css

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:red;">Name</td>
            <td style="color:red;">Info</td>
            <td style="color:red;">Surmane</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>AA</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>AAA</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>AAAA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>BB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>BBB</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>BBBB</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>CC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>CCC</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>CCCC</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi all,
According to my requirement i cannot modify this html code. so neither i add class nor add id in table.
The suggestion of Fabrizio Calderan is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.hey {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="hey">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Surmane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>AA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>AAA</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>AAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>BB</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>BBB</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>CC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>CCC</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why even have `:first-child` there? The class doesn't appear anywhere else.

Comment: You are right, just edited. I was trying a different approach before and didn't remove that

Answer (score 0):

You should set a class or id for your desired  tag and set background in css
as below (and please mark the answer as correct if helps you):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.TestClass{
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<table>
            <tr class="TestClass">
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Surmane</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>AA</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Age</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address</td>
                            <td>AAA</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>AAAA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>BB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Age</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address</td>
                            <td>BBB</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>BBBB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>CC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Age</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address</td>
                            <td>CCC</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>CCCC</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td > table tr:first-child td {
    background: none;
}
tr:first-child td {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```